# How to get a list of standard HTTP header names in Python

Tags: python, http, flask, http-headers

I'm writing a Flask app, and I want to avoid manually writing HTTP response header names, for obvious reasons.

Is there a list of standard HTTP header names in the stdlib (or in Flask), that I could import - so that I avoid writing stuff like this:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = ...
```

Comment: "for obvious reasons." I'm afraid they are not at all obvious at least to me. Care to elaborate? Is this in order to avoid repetition?

Comment: Manually typing Header names is prone to typos.

Comment: Okay, I see. Flask is largely built on top of [Werkzeug](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Werkzeug/). I'd check its [HTTP utilities](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/http/). But to be honest, I doubt you'll find anything.

Comment: I thought I'd find it in `http`, since it already has the `HTTPStatus` list - but nope. It's weird.

Comment: I guess there is little need for it. I also just realised, you may find something in [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html). The chances are slim again, though.

Answer (score 2):

After giving it some thought, I am afraid there will be little in Flask, Werkzeug or the stdlib. So here is a solution: Create your own [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) containing the desired header names. You can create that through the [IANA MEssage Header Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml). It comes as CSV, so you can generate the enum programmatically. Just see to it that field 3 (1-based) contains `http` and field 4 is `standard`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of headers you can use in your python code

```
>>> import headers
>>> headers.HEADERS.ACCEPT
'Accept'
>>> headers.HEADERS.CONTENT_TYPE
'Content-Type'
```

Git repo is here
https://github.com/Narengowda/http_headers/blob/master/headers.py

Comment: Looks good. Ever thought about contributing this to the stdlib? `http` seems like a good fit, since it already has a similar HTTPStatus class.

Comment: Actually, I created this repo, just for you minutes ago :)

Comment: Oh... well, do feel encouraged to share it upstream, as well! Thank you :)

Comment: Uh ... But that contains *all* headers. Including those reserved for mail and netnews. Please considder the filtering advices from my answer.